# Kernel configuration using bitbake menuconfig in yocto?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to remove some drivers from the yocto kernel using menuconfig like this below..

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

after all the configurations i generate the fragment.cfg with.

```
bitbake -c diffconfig virtual/kernel
```

Then i make a .bbappend file in recipes-kernel/linux directory and bitbake my image.

Now the problem is that all the configuration which i do is reset to the default everytime for some reason. how can i make the configuration permanent ?

Comment: When you say "reset to default everytime" what do you mean by "everytime"? everytime you bitbake? flash the image?

Comment: everytime i do bitbake -C compile virtual/kernel or bitbake virtual/kernel or bitbake image.. for all the commands it do the same...

Comment: How is your building environment set up? Are you using devtool? The image could be being built using another kernel configuration that wasn't affected by your changes.

Comment: i m using a distribution from stm. I am appending the recipe which is used for this distribution but still no luck https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/Menuconfig_or_how_to_configure_kernel

Comment: but why it reset  after diffconfig too? if e.g. i havent bitbake the recipe or image it shouldnt compile? but still it get reset after doing diffconfig too

Comment: It has been a while since I last dealt with Yocto, but have you tried building the image after doing the `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel` without doing a diffconfig? If I remember correctly, I was successful editing the kernel only with that.

Comment: yes that worked. But now the problem is how to make these changes permanent. i tried both the fragment.cfg as well as defconfig method both sets the config to default..

Comment: and i get these warning do_compile is tainted from a forced run as well as for build too

Comment: When you use -C or -c -f with bitbake, you are forcing it to do something it didn't want in the first place, hence the warning. To get rid of it (and have a sane build), you need to clean the shared-state cache (-c cleansstate) of the incriminated recipe (virtual/kernel in your case).

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to create own receipt and override default.
For example, we are using linux-yocto-rt kernel and create own receipt with name linux-yocto-rt and following files:

```
linux-yocto-rt\linux-yocto-rt_4.9.bb
linux-yocto-rt\linux-yocto-rt\defconfig
```

defconfig file changes default configuration.
In bb file you should add link to this file like:

```
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig "
```

You can always look inside [official documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#changing-the-configuration)

Comment: i tried it too but it doesnt work. after bitbake virtual/kernel, when i run the menuconfig i see the default config..and i get these warning do_compile is tainted from a forced run as well as for build too

Comment: It seems you're using the meta-stm32mp layer. From a quick read, you're probably missing:
`KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS += "${WORKDIR/my-fragment.config"` in your bbappend. If you want to use a full defconfig, you need to do `KERNEL_DEFCONFIG = ""` and `KERNEL_EXTERNAL_DEFCONFIG = "my-defconfig"` then you should be good.
c.f. https://github.com/leon-anavi/meta-stm32mp/blob/zeus/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-stm32mp.inc#L23